# Custom predecessors column in custom list

Tags: 2013, custom-list, filter, spservices

I have a list of tasks, custom list template not task list, where I have lookup column on another list Projects, so my tasks are grouped by that lookup column, by Projects.

I added predecessors column to Item content type and it is working fine, but due to so many items/tasks in my list, **Predecessors** column is pretty messy.

My question is, if there is possibility I can filter predecessors column, to show in predecessors window only items/tasks from particular project, like there is cascade drop down possibility with SPServices?

*To be more specific, on newform, after I choose project, in Predecessors column I would like to see only items from that project.*

If it is not possible to customize OOTB Predecessors column, do you know any way how could I create my own?